# htaccess category link optimization to main site

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have htaccess file with category link redirection to main site

Look my code below

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/shop/test1(/)?$
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/test1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/shop/test2(/)?$
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/test2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/shop/test3(/)?$
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/test3 [R=301,L]
```

Any other way to optimize the above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These 3 rules **can be combined into single rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^shop/(test1|test2|test3)/?$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```